# Cant find class inside controller index (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, model, controller

Hello guys I'm having trouble with `laravel.<b`
So I created controller called `PostController` with model `Post<br>`
So when I call `Post:all();` inside my index it shows `error<br>`

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Post' not found<br>
```

my code is here please help me I'll be so thankful :)

```
<br>
I am watching tutorial Traversy Media<br>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emyIlJPxZr4&t=1s<br>
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCKd7.png">
```

Comment: do u have `use App\Post;` in ur PostController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PostController

```
use App\Post;
class PostController
{
    // YOurr code.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `PostController` you need to include the `Post` class by adding the following after the namespace but before the class declaration:

`use App\Post;`

or update the above path by checking the namespace in your `Post` class